# Background color doesn't apply after changing visibility

Tags: javascript, html, css

The pink background color disappear after I change the visibility of the container ul tag. 
The codes are as follows. Did I miss something ? Why does the li doesn't inherit the background color of ul tag?

```
<style type="text/css">
.div_r3r4_container { width:760px; background-color:lightblue; } 
.div_r3_class     {  margin-left:132px; width:630px;  }
.ul_r3hz_class  { background-color:pink; font-size:0px; padding:2px 2px 1px 3px;list-style:none;margin:0;        }
.li_r3hz_class  { font-size:14px; color:black; display:inline;   }
.ul_r4hz_class {background-color:yellow; font-size:0px; border:1px solid red; padding:1px 2px 2px 3px;list-style:none;margin:0; }
.li_r4hz_class {font-size:14px; color:green; display:inline; }

</style>



<div  id="div_r3_r4_id" class="div_r3r4_container"> 
    <label id="city"> hide and show ul    </label> 

    <div  class="div_r3_class" >  
        <ul class="ul_r3hz_class" id="sid" >
           <li  class="li_r3hz_class"> aaaa, aaaa1, aaa2, aaa3,      </li> 
           <li  class="li_r3hz_class"> aaaaa4, aaaa5,  aaaa5,  aaa6,    </li>   
       </ul>
    </div>        

      <div  class="div_r4_class" >  
        <ul class="ul_r4hz_class"  >
           <li  class="li_r4hz_class"> bb, bbb, bbbb, bbbb2, bbbb3    </li> 
           <li  class="li_r4hz_class"> bbbb5, bbb6, bbb7, bbb8,    </li>   
       </ul>
    </div>        

</div>  



<div>
<input id="minus" value="-" type="submit" style="background-color:white; float:right; font-size:6px;" onClick="hide_show_div('sid', 'minus', 'plus' ); return flase; ">
<input id="plus" value="+" type="submit" style="background-color:white; float:right; font-size:6px;" onClick="show_hide_div('sid', 'minus','plus','div_r3_class' ); return flase; ">

</div>


<script language = "JavaScript">   

function hide_show_div( hideid1, hideid2, showid1 ){
    hideObjDiv( hideid1 ) ; 
    hideObjDiv( hideid2 ) ; 
    showObjDiv( showid1 ) ; 
}

function show_hide_div( showdivid1, showid2, hideid1, newclass ){
    hideObjDiv( hideid1 ) ; 
    showObjDiv( showid2 ) ; 
    showObjDiv( showdivid1 ) ; 
}
function hideObjDiv(obj) {
    if (document.getElementById) { 
        document.getElementById(obj).style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById(obj).style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function showObjDiv(obj) {
    if (document.getElementById) { 
        document.getElementById(obj).style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById(obj).style.display = 'inline';
    } 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Could you specify which element exactly it is you are hiding?

Comment: Just click on the  "-", you will see the pink aaaa text disappear. Then click the "+" it will come back up but the background color is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a problem in your javascript code. As you may know, unordered list tag should be block by default and you are trying to make it inline in your js code (after hiding). Just try to change your showObjDiv function to something like this:

```
function showObjDiv(obj) {
    if (document.getElementById) { 
        document.getElementById(obj).style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById(obj).style.display = 'block';
    } 
}
```

It should work just fine after that.

Comment: Also, please, fix return flase; (seems like a typo) in your html part.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between setting **visibility:hidden** and **display:none** . when you set **display:none** the element will be completely removed from the flow and this element along with all its attributes and styles will be deleted. If ***obj*** element has css class *div_r3_class* then (for the sake of simplicity I used jQuery) :

```
function showObjDiv(obj) {
    if (document.getElementById) { 
        document.getElementById(obj).style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById(obj).style.display = 'inline';
        $("#"+obj).addClass('div_r3_class');
    }
```

In this way after re-displaying the element, the specified class will be attached to it.